# Can submit grid field data

Tags: grid

I've got this error `You are not authorized to perform this action` using grid field in ExpressionEngine 2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in 2.9 see this bug report https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20462/